# Cannot implicitly convert Lazy<Class> to Lazy<Interface>

Tags: c#, interface, initialization, lazy-initialization

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and I have a question in regards to using an `interface` with `Lazy<T> initialization`.

Here is the class definition in question:

```
public class WebAPITokenService1_0 : IWebApiTokenService
```

Here is my code that works with out using the interface in the declaration:

Declaration:

```
Lazy<WebAPITokenService1_0> webAPITokenService1_0;
```

Initialization:

```
webAPITokenService1_0 = new Lazy<WebAPITokenService1_0>();
```

Here is the same code, but with using an interface:

Declaration:

```
Lazy<IWebApiTokenService> webAPITokenService1_0;
```

Initialization:

```
webAPITokenService1_0 = new Lazy<WebAPITokenService1_0>();
```

Here is the error when using the `interface` in the declaration:

```
> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Lazy<CanFindLocation.Services.AndroidWebAPI._1_0.WebAPITokenService1_0>'
> to
> 'System.Lazy<CanFindLocation.Interfaces.WebService.IWebApiTokenService>'  E:\CanFindLocation\MVC\CanFindLocation\CanFindLocation\Controllers\AndroidWebAPI\1_0\WebService1_0Controller.cs
```

I have had a look at the [Lazy Initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286(v=vs.110).aspx), but cannot see any information about the above situation.

Can I use an `interface` with `Lazy<T> initialization`, and if so, what is incorrect with my above code?

Comment: `Lazy<IWebApiTokenService> webAPITokenService1_0=new Lazy<IWebApiTokenService>(() => new WebAPITokenService1_0());`

Comment: Thank you. I will accept this is answer if you would like to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET supports generic variance only for interfaces and delegates, and `Lazy<T>` is a class. So you can not assign `Lazy<Derived>` instance to `Lazy<Base>` variable

However, you can create a `Lazy<Base>` instance that contains `Derived` instance as its `Value` property by using the `Lazy<T>` constructor that accepts a factory delegate as an argument:

```
Lazy<Base> lazy1 = new Lazy<Base>(() => new Derived(args1));
Lazy<Base> lazy2 = new Lazy<Base>(() => GetDerived(args2));
```

Comment: Good answer.  I was having trouble understanding what OP was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

`Lazy<T>` does not support [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you must use exactly the same type in the declaration and initialization.